# Activator from guest OS

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm working on a project that is being converted from Groovy and Grails to Play Framework using Scala.

The app includes integration with native windows libraries, but I do my primary development on OSX only switching over to a Windows guest when I run the full app or tests that are dependent on the native libraries.

Using this setup the project files exist on the host file system and are shared with the Windows guest as a shared folder. This setup worked flawlessly for Grails development, but with the switch to Play Framework and Activator I'm encountering a **java.io.IOException: incorrect function** error when attempting to execute run via activator.

I can successfully compile and run tests. Additionally, I can successfully create and run new play projects from the guest, just can't run the project from the hosts shared folder. Any ideas how to resolve this?

I'm using the latest play framework download as of yesterday. So Play v2.4.3 with Activator v1.3.6. The project was created by running "activator new" and selecting the play-scala template. No changes were made to the template. The host OS is OSX and the guest OS is Windows 7. Java SDK 1.8.0_65

The activator run stacktrace:

```
[freshproject] $ run
java.io.IOException: Incorrect function.
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.implRegister(WindowsWatchService.java:407)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.processRequests(AbstractPoller.java:260)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.io.IOException: Incorrect function.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 28, 2015 6:30:56 AM
[freshproject] $ last compile:run
java.io.IOException: Incorrect function.
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.implRegister(WindowsWatchService.java:407)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.processRequests(AbstractPoller.java:260)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (compile:run) java.io.IOException: Incorrect function.
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace? also what version of activator & play are you on?